# cxf Web Service doesn't update

Tags: java, web-services, spring, deployment, cxf

I've constructed a CXF Webservice like so -

Interface:

```
package de.arvato.icssa.services;

import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService
public interface TestService {
    String sayHi(String text);
    boolean startProcess(String mail, String processName, String locale);
}
```

Implementation:

```
package de.arvato.icssa.endpoints;

import javax.jws.WebService;
import java.util.*;

import de.arvato.icssa.util.*;


import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;

import de.arvato.icssa.db.HibernateUtil;
import de.arvato.icssa.db.worker.TaskWorker;
import de.arvato.icssa.services.TestService;

@WebService(endpointInterface="de.arvato.icssa.services.TestService")
public class TestServiceImpl implements TestService{

private Log log = LogFactory.getLog(this.getClass());
@Override
public String sayHi(String text)
{
    System.out.println("sayHi called");
    return "Hello " + text;
}

public boolean startProcess(String mail, String processName, String locale)
{ 
         <<<<<CODE>>>>>>
}
}
```

cxf.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">

<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />

<jaxws:endpoint id="testService"
    implementor="de.arvato.icssa.endpoints.TestServiceImpl" address="/TestService" />

</beans>
```

Important part of web.xml:

```
 <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/cxf.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/TestService</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/TestService/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This generally worked fine. My Method "startProcess" used to have 2 parameters (omitting the "locale") - I recently added it, restarted my Tomcat 6.0 Webserver which I've integrated into the "Servers" Eclipse plugin - but that Method will still only accept 2 parameters and run the old code that I've had inside that method before added the third parameter.

**EDIT**

**If I implemented another Method it also isn't updated after restarting the server, it appears as though nothing changes. My Webservice is still updated in its original form.**

Any ideas about how I can do a "hard" re-deploy of that webservice?

Thanks!

Comment: did you remove the old WAR and deploy the new one? Did you try it via tomcat manager GUI and via eclipse?

Comment: I'm not fluent with the whole concept of web programming in java in general - I've simply restarted the server via the eclipse Servers plugin since that seemed to do the trick before. Not sure how to locate the other alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the server tab right click the server and click republish. If that doesn't help, right click and choose Add/Remove project and remove the project, then right click again choose Add/Remove project and add it again.

If that didn't help either, you can right click the project and choose export->War file. Export it to whatever location you want.

Go to TOMCAT_HOME/webapps, delete your project if it is there and copy the new war file under it.

Let me know if that helped.

Comment: Thanks, for your answer, I've republished my project and I exported it to WAR and tried running it, alas it still displays the old version of my webservice. Even if I delete methods and restart/publish nothing changes.

Comment: When I check my deployed Webapp and open the .class file of my Service, I still see the "sayHi" Method which I've just deleted a few minutes ago ... maybe this helps.

Comment: It means that your project is not being built(compiled), in the upper menu go to Project and make sure Build automatically is selected

Comment: But now that you mention it, it doesn't matter which class I update, the old version is always deployed.

Comment: On the top menu click Project->clean, if that doesn't help try to restart eclipse

Comment: Unfortunately neither suggestion solved the problem - but I think I made "progress", now I haven't got the old class files in my project - I've got none. I can navigate as far as ICSSA\WEB-INF\classes\path\to\packages -> no content.

Comment: the clean command deletes the class files and then eclipse should recompile them, for some reason eclipse is not compiling your java files.